# Gaming on Virtual Machines with 1 GPU

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I have a fairly powerful system and am trying to play a game with 2 other friends. The game itself is not too resource intensive, so the computer can definitely handle the load, but I'm stuck with trying to configure it to work on the same GPU and some remote access stuff.

System specs:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 3 2200g
- Memory: 64GB Corsair Vengeance LPX 2666mhz
- Motherboard: ASUS ROG STRIX b450-f
- GPU: RTX 2080

So my first issue...
When I try to run the game in the VM (I was able to get Windows installed and everything on both VMs and am using VirtualBox), it gives me an error saying this machine doesn't have support for OpenGL. I checked with Task Manager, Device Manager, CPU-Z, and NVidia's driver installer and the GPU is not being detected by either machine. How can I make it so this GPU is being shared by all 3 machines? If VirtualBox doesn't have this feature, is there another (preferably free) virtual machine software that does?

My second issue...
I can't seem to remote desktop to any machine on any port other than 3389 (Microsoft's default remote desktop port). Currently, I have my host system hosting to 3389 so I'd like to host my VMs on 3390 and 3391. I made sure to port forward, configure the remote port in VirtualBox, change it in Windows Registry, and enable remote desktop in windows, yet I can't connect to either machine from my local network, or a nonlocal network.

If anyone has any ideas for solutions, let me know.
All help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

To date I haven't seen a way to utilize a system's GPU through VMs it hosts (beyond the 2GB limit). You could try accessing your VMs through VMware Workstation Player to get through the OpenGL problem, though I've noticed my VMs come up as unlicensed (Windows 7) when accessed through it (not sure why).

Changing RDP ports is pretty easy; just a tweak of the registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber

Ensure your value is set to decimal (from hex) and assign whatever port number you want.

Hope that helps.